# Populate a given time period/time sequence by IDs

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, lubridate

Assume a df like this:

```
df <- data.frame(end_date = as.Date("2007-10-10", format = "%Y-%m-%d"))

    end_date
1 2007-10-10
```

I want to generate a monthly sequence of dates starting with a given date and going back N months (in this case 11 months). After that, I want to assign a group ID to every N months (in this example, it is 2 months). I can do this by:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
 mutate(start_date = end_date %m-% months(11),
        date = list(seq.Date(start_date, end_date, by = "month"))) %>%
 unnest() %>%
 arrange(desc(date)) %>%
 mutate(ID = gl(ceiling(n()/3), 3, length = n()))

     end_date start_date       date ID
1  2007-10-10 2006-11-10 2007-10-10  1
2  2007-10-10 2006-11-10 2007-09-10  1
3  2007-10-10 2006-11-10 2007-08-10  1
4  2007-10-10 2006-11-10 2007-07-10  2
5  2007-10-10 2006-11-10 2007-06-10  2
6  2007-10-10 2006-11-10 2007-05-10  2
7  2007-10-10 2006-11-10 2007-04-10  3
8  2007-10-10 2006-11-10 2007-03-10  3
9  2007-10-10 2006-11-10 2007-02-10  3
10 2007-10-10 2006-11-10 2007-01-10  4
11 2007-10-10 2006-11-10 2006-12-10  4
12 2007-10-10 2006-11-10 2006-11-10  4
```

This is the tricky part. I want to have the "end_date" of subsequent groups to be the "start_date" of previous group and the "start_date" to be adjusted according to this move, meaning the IDs will still have the same number of months. I was able to create a semi-functional solution:

```
df %>%
 mutate(start_date = end_date %m-% months(11),
        date = list(seq.Date(start_date, end_date, by = "month"))) %>%
 unnest() %>%
 arrange(desc(date)) %>%
 mutate(ID = gl(ceiling(n()/3), 3, length = n())) %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 summarise(start_date = min(date),
           end_date = max(date)) %>%
 mutate(start_date = if_else(ID != 1, start_date %m+% months(row_number() - 1), start_date),
        end_date = if_else(ID != 1, end_date %m+% months(row_number() - 1), end_date))

  ID    start_date end_date  
  <fct> <date>     <date>    
1 1     2007-08-10 2007-10-10
2 2     2007-06-10 2007-08-10
3 3     2007-04-10 2007-06-10
4 4     2007-02-10 2007-04-10
```

The problem is, however, that it does not populate the entire initial period (12 months) by groups. There could be potentially more IDs until reaching the original "start_date", i.e. `2006-11-10`.

For this given example, there is a fifth ID **(this is also the desired output)**:

```
  ID start_date   end_date
1  1 2007-08-10 2007-10-10
2  2 2007-06-10 2007-08-10
3  3 2007-04-10 2007-06-10
4  4 2007-02-10 2007-04-10
5  5 2006-12-10 2007-02-10
```

Therefore, my question is, is there any possibility to populate a given time period by the logic described above?

Answer (score 1):

If this corresponds to the output you're after, a more straightforward approach might be the following:

- Define `date` based on a sequence of months defined by `month_start`
- Get `start_date` by cutting `date` column into `month_step`-month intervals using `cut`
- Define `end_date` by relabeling the factor `start_date` (shifting up the levels)
- Define `id` by relabeling the levels in `start_date` as integers

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

month_data <- function(end_date = "2007-10-10", month_start = -12, month_step = 2) {

  tibble(date = as.Date(end_date) + months(0:month_start)) %>%
      mutate(
          start_date = cut(date, 
              breaks = as.Date(end_date) + months(0:(month_start %/% month_step) * month_step), 
              include.lowest = TRUE),
          end_date = as.Date(factor(start_date, labels = c(tail(levels(start_date), -1), end_date))), 
          ID = factor(start_date, labels = seq_len(nlevels(start_date))),
          start_date = as.Date(start_date)
      )
}


## 12-month sequence + 2-month intervals
month_data()
#> # A tibble: 13 x 4
#>    date       start_date end_date   ID   
#>    <date>     <date>     <date>     <fct>
#>  1 2007-10-10 2007-08-10 2007-10-10 6    
#>  2 2007-09-10 2007-08-10 2007-10-10 6    
#>  3 2007-08-10 2007-08-10 2007-10-10 6    
#>  4 2007-07-10 2007-06-10 2007-08-10 5    
#>  5 2007-06-10 2007-06-10 2007-08-10 5    
#>  6 2007-05-10 2007-04-10 2007-06-10 4    
#>  7 2007-04-10 2007-04-10 2007-06-10 4    
#>  8 2007-03-10 2007-02-10 2007-04-10 3    
#>  9 2007-02-10 2007-02-10 2007-04-10 3    
#> 10 2007-01-10 2006-12-10 2007-02-10 2    
#> 11 2006-12-10 2006-12-10 2007-02-10 2    
#> 12 2006-11-10 2006-10-10 2006-12-10 1    
#> 13 2006-10-10 2006-10-10 2006-12-10 1

## 12-month sequence + 3-month intervals
month_data(month_step = 3)
#> # A tibble: 13 x 4
#>    date       start_date end_date   ID   
#>    <date>     <date>     <date>     <fct>
#>  1 2007-10-10 2007-07-10 2007-10-10 4    
#>  2 2007-09-10 2007-07-10 2007-10-10 4    
#>  3 2007-08-10 2007-07-10 2007-10-10 4    
#>  4 2007-07-10 2007-07-10 2007-10-10 4    
#>  5 2007-06-10 2007-04-10 2007-07-10 3    
#>  6 2007-05-10 2007-04-10 2007-07-10 3    
#>  7 2007-04-10 2007-04-10 2007-07-10 3    
#>  8 2007-03-10 2007-01-10 2007-04-10 2    
#>  9 2007-02-10 2007-01-10 2007-04-10 2    
#> 10 2007-01-10 2007-01-10 2007-04-10 2    
#> 11 2006-12-10 2006-10-10 2007-01-10 1    
#> 12 2006-11-10 2006-10-10 2007-01-10 1    
#> 13 2006-10-10 2006-10-10 2007-01-10 1

## 10 month sequence + 5-month intervals
month_data(month_start = -10, month_step = 5)
#> # A tibble: 11 x 4
#>    date       start_date end_date   ID   
#>    <date>     <date>     <date>     <fct>
#>  1 2007-10-10 2007-05-10 2007-10-10 2    
#>  2 2007-09-10 2007-05-10 2007-10-10 2    
#>  3 2007-08-10 2007-05-10 2007-10-10 2    
#>  4 2007-07-10 2007-05-10 2007-10-10 2    
#>  5 2007-06-10 2007-05-10 2007-10-10 2    
#>  6 2007-05-10 2007-05-10 2007-10-10 2    
#>  7 2007-04-10 2006-12-10 2007-05-10 1    
#>  8 2007-03-10 2006-12-10 2007-05-10 1    
#>  9 2007-02-10 2006-12-10 2007-05-10 1    
#> 10 2007-01-10 2006-12-10 2007-05-10 1    
#> 11 2006-12-10 2006-12-10 2007-05-10 1
```

Comment: That you for your effort. There are two problems with your solution. First, I don't see that it could be easily scaled to every N month (here it is 2, but it could 3, 4 etc.). Second, it generates IDs that overreaches the original date (`2006-11-10` vs `2006-10-10`).

Comment: @tmfmnk: I edited the reponse adding an additional filter and cutting by 3-month intervals instead of 2-month intervals. Perhaps this is closer to what you want to achieve, it is a bit unclear from the question how the IDs are defined, as the `start_date`-`end_date` IDs do not seem to correspond to the `date` IDs

Comment: The "date" column is a N month (here 12 month) sequence between "start_date" and "end_date". The "start_month" column is calculated from the given "end_date" column. Based on "date" column, an initial set of IDs is generated so that for every N months (here for every two months) a unique ID is assigned.

Comment: @tmfmk: I suppose "start_month" refers to "start_date" and the two N's are unrelated? What I meant in the previous comment is that e.g. 2007-05-10 gets ID 2 in the initial `df`, but is not in the interval with ID 2 (2007-06-10 to 2007-08-10) in the final `df`.

Comment: You are right, by "start_month" I meant "start_date" :) And the final ID is not entirely in its original interval because of the moves it takes. It means that the "end_date" column becomes the "start_date" of the previous ID. The "start_date" is then adjusted accordingly, to still have N months (in this case 2). So, the final "start_date" is "end_date" - 2 months, while the "end_date" is the "start_date" of a previous ID.